# Find Constants from CDF

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a CDF:

[image]

Find the constants a and b

Assume that the median of X is 0.7.

My understanding of finding the constants from a CDF is to integrate the given function from 0 to 1. 
By putting the given CDF F(x) = 1. Is my assumption correct or the approach I explained above only works from PDF?

Comment: Has the question given that $X$ is a (absolutely) continuous random variable? (no point mass at $X = 1$ actually) If yes, you can use the continuity at $x = 1$ as one of the condition, combine with the median condition, you have $2$ equations to solve for $2$ unknowns

Comment: @BGM the question states "The continuous random variable X has the cumulative distribution function "

Comment: Generally, continuous random variables are taken to mean random variables whose distributions are continuous everywhere and (furthermore) _absolutely continuous_ (i.e. differentiable) everywhere except possibly at a set of discrete points (where the distributions continue to be continuous but fail to be absolutely continuous and so are not differentiable). So, use this together with the hint in BGM's comment re continuity of the CDF at $x=1$.